# Does estrogen have a more potent neural pruning effect in adolescence than testosterone?

Tags: neuroscience, sexual-dimorphism

I have read a study [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4504753/) which finds that female rats with their oestrogen inhibited had more neurones in a region of the visual cortex than intact female rats. To me, this suggests that estrogen may have a more potent neural pruning effect than testosterone, and that this may explain why female brains are on average slightly smaller than male ones. However, this study is A) not on humans and B) not on the whole brain. Further, the difference between average brain weight extends into childhood when sex hormones are low (but not non-existent. So, I wanted to know whether there was any consensus on the difference between testosterone-controlled neural pruning and estrogen-controlled neural pruning, and whether my conjecture is reflected by any evidence.